# Laravel change database connection on a live server

Tags: laravel, caching

On a live server i changed the database connection and it did not listen to the change

I think the Dasebase connection is cashed

locally i can restart the server and use

```
php artisan config:cache
```

i tried also

```
Route::get('/clear-cache', function() {
    $exitCode = Artisan::call('cache:clear');
    return '<h1>clear cached</h1>';
    // return what you want
});
```

put it didn't read the new route ,i think the routes is cashed as well 
so what to do in order to make Laravel read the new database connection

Comment: Define "I changed the database connection". Where did you change it?

Comment: in .env file ...

Comment: try `php artisan config:clear`

Comment: how can i do that on a live server not a local server ?

Comment: Yeah, config:clear or cache:clear it should work

Comment: in your project folder, open a command promt

Comment: Same as on the local server, go to the terminal and run the php artisan commands

Comment: i dont know to open a command promt on a live server
i know only how to do taht on a local server

Comment: How do you deploy/copy the files from local to live server?

Comment: locally i can browse to the server using cd thePath
how to do that on the live seerver

Comment: using ftp with  filezaila

Comment: Yeah, filezilla was fine about 10 years ago, you should learn git and deploy it with git commands. And which Operating System do you use? So I can tell you how can you access the servers terminal.

Comment: windows os localy and server use linux

Comment: So just install Putty and use the same credentials like you use for filezilla and then you can access the server terminal

Answer (score 0):

Connect SSH into server and run:

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
```

Should help :)